# Invalid YAML preventing me from sending an email?

Tags: configuration, yaml, symfony4

So I am workig on a Symfony API, I am trying to send an email via SwiftMailer, I set it my code right, I tried to set my configuration file too, but I think I am getting an error.

Here is my swiftmailer.yaml configuration file :

```
swiftmailer:
    transport:       gmail
    host:            localhost
    port:            465
    encryption:      ssl
    auth-mode:       login 
    username:        "****@gmail.com"
    password:        "*******"
    spool: 
        { type: "memory" }
    stream_options:
    ssl:
      allow_self_signed: true
      verify_peer: false
      verify_peer_name: false
```

But When I try to execute my code, I get this error :

> The file
>   "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Learn\symfprojs\correctsymf\config/packages/swiftmailer.yaml"
>   does not contain valid YAML: Reference "***@gmail.com" does n     ot
>   exist at line 6 (near "username:        ****@gmail.com") in
>   C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Learn\symfprojs\correctsymf\config/packages/swiftmailer.yaml
>   (which is      loaded in resource
>   "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Learn\symfprojs\correctsymf\config/packages/swiftmailer.yaml").

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your config in the top level of the file, but it should be under the key `mailers.%mailer_name%`. Assuming your application only has one mailer:

```
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: default
    mailers:
        default:
            transport: gmail
            # ...
```